# How can I retrieve a specific member from a class with a getter inside of a function that uses an iterator inside of a loop?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I'm trying to make a function that returns a class (CTaxGroup) by taking as parameter a TaxGroupId.

The function will loop through a vector with an iterator.

```
int m_TaxGroupId;

CTaxGroup CTaxGroupVector::FetchTaxGroup(int TaxGroupId)
{
    CTaxGroup l_TaxGroup;
    std::vector<CTaxGroup>::iterator l_iterator =m_TaxGroupVector.begin();
    for(l_iterator; l_iterator != m_TaxGroupVector.end(); l_iterator++)
    {
        int l_TaxGroupId = *l_iterator->GetTaxGroupId();
        if(l_TaxGroupId == TaxGroupId)
        {
            l_TaxGroup = *l_iterator;
        }
    }
    return l_TaxGroup;
}

std::vector<CTaxGroup> CTaxGroupVector::GetTaxGroupVector()
{
    return m_TaxGroupVector;
}
```

At line 7, I get an error from my IDE (RAD Studio XE4) which states :
"E2062 Invalid indirection".

I know that it was something to do with the pointer, but I'm not sure what is my error.

I'm expecting that line 7 would return me an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, since you don't provide a compilable program, it's likely that you should put parentheses around the initial dereferencing, `(*l_iterator)->GetTaxGroupId()`, so that the compiler knows you're trying to access a member of a `CTaxGroup`, not a member of an iterator.

Comment: It ended up being ```(*l_iterator).GetTaxGroupId()```.
I had know idea I had to put parenthesis. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherNguyenHoang No problem, the order of operations on pointers can be confusing.